# Copy content from one file to multiple file using java

Tags: java, file

```
FileInputStream Fread = new FileInputStream("somefilename"); 
FileOutputStream Fwrite = null;

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    String fileName = "file" + i + ".txt";
    Fwrite = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    int c; 

    while ((c = Fread.read()) != -1) 
    {
        Fwrite.write((char) c);
    }

    Fwrite.close();
}

Fread.close();
```

The above code writes only to one file. How to make it work to write the content of one file to multiple files?

Comment: You need to go back to the beginning of the input file for each output file.

Comment: @ScottHunter why? you are talking about multiple reads, not writes, why can't he just make 3 outputstreams and write to all of them as he reads?

Comment: I’m not saying he can’t do that, nor that he shouldn’t; it is just a bigger change to the program.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
Fread.reset();
```

after `Fwrite.close();`

And change the first line of code to this:

```
InputStream Fread = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("somefilename"));
Fread.mark(0);
```

Comment: it produces error
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
 at java.io.InputStream.reset(Unknown Source)

Comment: @ShubhamSiddhartha I think answers by Mahozard and vikas tandon miss the point of your question.

Comment: This could work, but is inefficient because it reads the input file multiple times. Andreas's answer is correct and efficient.

Comment: Just a simple answer with minimum modification to the original code :)

Comment: should outputstream need to be buffered?

Comment: Yes I think its better to be buffered.

Comment: still showing error after making outputstream buffered
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)

Comment: @Mahozad i made changes which you told , but still its throwing some error

Comment: Make sure that your file names are correct if you see this exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: The code works for me fine; if you get any error, that is another problem that you could easily search for

Comment: Can you send your demonstration or working code?
@Mahozad

Comment: I think you need to mark the position before resting, as what reset, resets to the mark position

Comment: `InputStream Fread = new BufferedInputStream(new 
    FileInputStream("example.txt"));

        Fread.mark(0);

        FileOutputStream Fwrite = null;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {

            String fileName = "file" + i + ".txt";

            Fwrite = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

            int c;

            while ((c = Fread.read()) != -1)
            {

                Fwrite.write((char) c);

            }

            Fwrite.close();

            Fread.reset();

        }

        Fread.close();`

Comment: Got the expected output. we cannot use reset without marking the position from where we want to reset as compiler doesn't know what to do.
So before using reset we need to mark at the beginning of the file.
Thanks @Mahozad
But still i have doubt is it the efficient way to do this?

Comment: No as another user said it's not the efficient way to do it

Comment: Well any thoughts on how to efficiently do it?

Comment: but i just tried to help you with minimum modification and in a simple way

Comment: You just wrap your `outputStream`s in `BufferedOutputStream`s and instead of rereading the input every time, just as you read it, write to output files (by initializing all outputStreams once together in a loop and then in your while loop write to every one of them)

Comment: I add another efficient answer if you want?

Comment: [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/861/java-copy-file) you can see best methods to copy files.

Answer (score 2):

*FYI:* Note that the [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) method you used returns a `byte`, not a `char`, so calling `write((char) c)` should have been just [`write(c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-int-).

---

To write to multiple files in parallel when copying a file, you create a array of output streams for the destination files, then iterate the array to write the data to all of them.

For better performance, you should always do this using a buffer. Writing one byte at a time will not perform well.

```
public static void copyToMultipleFiles(String inFile, String... outFiles) throws IOException {
    OutputStream[] outStreams = new OutputStream[outFiles.length];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < outFiles.length; i++)
            outStreams[i] = new FileOutputStream(outFiles[i]);
        try (InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(inFile)) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[16384];
            for (int len; (len = inStream.read(buf)) > 0; )
                for (OutputStream outStream : outStreams)
                    outStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    } finally {
        for (OutputStream outStream : outStreams)
            if (outStream != null)
                outStream.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create multiple instances of `FileOutputStream` `fwrite1`, `fwrite2`, `fwrite3`, one per each file you want to write to, then, as you read, you simply write to all of them. This is how you achieve it.

Comment: How can i do that in for loop, what if loop runs for 100 time
so i don't think it will be effective solution

Comment: @ShubhamSiddhartha it is more effective than reading every time from a file and then writing to another file. Are you considering to run multiple threads for writing or something? You didn't talk about that in your question.

Answer (score -1):

The `FRead`stream gets to the end once and then there is nothing to make it start from the beginning.
To solve this you can:

- call to `FRead.reset()` after each file writing
- cache `FRead`'s value somewhere and write to `FWrite` from this source
- create an array / collection of `FileOutputStream` and write each byte to all of them during iteration

The recommended solution is of course the first one.

Also there are some problems in your code:

- You are highly encouraged to use try-with-resouce for Streams as they should be safely closed
- You seem to not follow naming conventions which say to name variables in lowerCamelCase